# Prevent Erroneous Property Assignment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Porting android applications to iphone applications always gives me the following pattern that I accidentally create:

```
- (void) myFunc:(id)prop {
    self.property = property;
}
```

Which instead should be:

```
- (void) myFunc:(id)prop {
    self.property = prop;
}
```

This always causes my program to quietly break because property gets reset to its existing value rather than being set to the new value, 'prop'. I cannot name the parameter 'prop' to 'property' since the compile complains that the parameter masks the instance variables visibility.

Is there a good way to avoid this situation? There are no compiler warnings. Is there a way to make xcode prevent this? I cannot see very many situations where you would set a property to the value of its underlying instance variable (maybe to trigger a KVO binding?), but I don't see myself doing that in majority of cases.

I understand the above code is synthetic and should be done with @synthesize, but I am just using it as a simplified example to illustrate my point.

Comment: Not sure why you got down voted.  Perfectly valid question.  At the least, file an enhancement request via bug report.apple.com as the static analyzer should catch this.

Comment: What about editing the setter to log whenever you try to set the property to itself? Of course, that may be more trouble than just checking this function

Comment: The function as written in your example is completely redundant.  You should just use the property directly, since it is itself a setter and getter method.

Comment: @JeremyP yes, I realize this (hence the last sentence in my question). Image a larger function that has lots of parameters and sets lots of properties (an initializer maybe?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many people choose to name their instance variables with a leading underscore. This would allow you to name your parameter `property`, and it's unlikely you'd accidentally type an underscore.

Or, you could name your parameter `newProperty`, which might make it different enough that it'd be harder to confuse?

Comment: Was hoping this wasn't going to be the answer, but guess it is!

Comment: Sorry! I don't like it either. :)